# GKE not able to pull image from artifactory

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, jfrog-cli

I am using GKE, gitlab and JFrog to achieve CI and CD. All my steps work, but my deployment to GKE fails as its not able to poll my image. Image does exists. I have given below deployment, yaml and error message.

Below is my deployment file, i have hardcoded the image to be clear that image does exists.

```
--- 
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: go
  name: hello-world-go
spec: 
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 3
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: go
  strategy: 
    rollingUpdate: 
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 33%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: go
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
         # image: "<IMAGE_NAME>"
          image: cicd-docker-local.jfrog.io/stage_proj:56914646
          livenessProbe: 
            httpGet: 
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 2
          name: go
          ports: 
            - 
              containerPort: 8080
          readinessProbe: 
            httpGet: 
              path: /healthz
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 2
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: my.secret
```

Below is my gitlab yaml file snippet

```
deploy to dev:
  stage: Dev-Deploy
  image: dtzar/helm-kubectl
  script:
    - kubectl config set-cluster mycluster --server="$KUBE_URL" --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
    - kubectl config set-credentials admin --username="$KUBE_USER" --password="$KUBE_PASSWORD"
    - kubectl config set-context default --cluster=mycluster --user=admin
    - kubectl config use-context default; sleep 10
    - kubectl delete secret my.secret
    - kubectl create secret docker-registry  my.secret --docker-server=$ARTIFACTORY_DOCKER_REPOSITORY --docker-username=$ARTIFACTORY_USER --docker-password=$ARTIFACTORY_PASS --docker-email="abc@gmail.com"
    - echo ${STAGE_CONTAINER_IMAGE}
    - kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
    - kubectl rollout status -w "deployment/hello-world-go"
   # - kubectl rollout status -f deployment.yaml
    - kubectl get all,ing -l app='hello-world-go'
  only:
    - master
```

I get error like below in GKE.

```
Cannot pull image 'cicd-docker-local.jfrog.io/stage_proj:56914646' from the registry.
```

Comment: How do you create `my.secret` Secret with the artifactory credentials? I can see `docker-registry` being created but it's not referenced as `imagePullsecret`

Comment: @AnnaSlastnikova - There was a typo error. secret key is my.secret. Do u find any other issue?

Comment: What is actual error in gke? You can check “Events” tab for a pod.